# Using Toggle for Comments Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been browsing stack overflow for an answer, and I can't quite find the error to my code.

I'm currently trying to create a toggle function with javascript for my comments section (displayed as an input form) so it hides/shows based on a button click.  Here is my code:

```
$("<button />", {
    "class": "btn btn-primary",
    "text": "Show Comments",
    "on-click": "showhidecomments()"
}).appendTo(wrapper);

$("form />",{
    "class": "comment-sec",
    "placeholder": "Add comments here",
    "input type": "text",
    "input type": "submit",
    "display": "none"
}).appendTo(wrapper);

// Show/hide comment box with input fields
var showhidecomments = function () {
('.comment-sec').toggle();

};
```

The error I keep getting on the console is: Uncaught TypeError: Object .comment-sec has no method 'toggle'

I don't think I am using toggle wrong - why else would this lead to an object error?

Comment: missing `$`.. `$('.comment-sec').toggle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `$`

```
var showhidecomments = function () {
    $('.comment-sec').toggle();
//  ^ missing here
};
```

There are few more problems like

```
$("<button />", {
    "class": "btn btn-primary",
    "text": "Show Comments",
    "onclick": "showhidecomments()" //should be onclick
}).appendTo(wrapper);

//it should be <form> not form>
$("<form />", {
    "class": "comment-sec",
    "display": "none"
}).hide().appendTo(wrapper);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aLXwX/)

Also I would recommend using jQuery to add the click handler instead of using inline attribute

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aLXwX/2/)

Comment: Thank you!  It works perfectly on jsfiddle - the comment boxes are still not appearing in my code, but I assume there must be something else impacting (not related with this question).